# Laravel get Auth variable for both - api token and session based authentication

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I am using `laravel 5.2`.

Recently, I've updated `Auth` module to have `session` based authentication for web and `api_token` based authentication for external api calls.

Now, I am finding error in using `Auth::id()` and `Auth::user()` where I've used `api_token` based authentication. So that I am forced to use `Auth::guard('api')->id()` and `Auth::guard('api')->user()` methods instead.

Now, my question is, is there any common method that I can use for both irrespective of `api_token` based authentication or `session` based? What about `auth()->user()` and `auth()->id()`?

What if am I using the any method for both of the authentication? For example, `methodA()` is used within `api_token` based authentication as well as in `session` based too, how can I handle that case if I required to use `Auth` variable?

Answer (score 1):

I think that controllers, that handle regular requests (through session-based authentication), should be separate from api controllers (token-based authentication). So, each controller would have responsibility over a single part of the functionality. Also, changes in api controller will not have side effect in session controller. Therefore, you can specify auth guard explicitly in each controller. Laravel requires specifying guard explicitly, otherwise default guard will be used. There is no way to make intelligent guess about what guard to use natively. Of course, you can make something like this:

```php
public function action(Request $request)
{
    $guard = $request->has('api_token') ? 'api' : 'session';
    $authUser = Auth::guard($guard)->user();

    //your code next
}
```

If you will go with separate controllers you can generalize common functionality into parent abstract controller. Note, in example below ChildControllers differs only by namespace.
Parent:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

abstract class ParentController extends Controller
{
    public function action(Request $request)
    {
        $authUser = Auth::guard($this->guard)->user();

        //your code...
    }
}
```

API controller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api

use App\Http\Controllers\ParentController

class ChildController extends ParentController
{
    protected $guard = 'api';

    //your code...
}
```

Session Controller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Session

use App\Http\Controllers\ParentController

class ChildController extends ParentController
{
    protected $guard = 'session';

    //your code...
}
```